How did MinGW port GCC to Windows?
I'm trying to understand how MinGW ported GCC to Windows. I know that GCC originates from the Unix world and, for myriad reasons, cannot simply be copied across to Windows as an executable nor built from source using the native toolchain provided by Windows. This is because program creation and execution differ between Unix and Windows.
Specifically, I understand that GCC needs to interface with the operating system through runtime libraries found in expected locations. Assuming that the analog of these libraries are the DLLs found on Windows, then GCC somehow has to link with these DLLs instead.
Using GCC as a concrete example, I'd like to know: What did MinGW change in the GCC source and build to port it to Windows?
I've looked at the MinGW-w64 source, but it was beyond my comprehension. I've also tried reading the Wikipedia pages for both MinGW and MinGW-w64 to learn about their context and aims. However, I still feel like I haven't answered my question.

I don't think that GCC had really been ported to Windows, instead it uses a lightweight compatibility layer that provides the *nix environment GCC has been developed for. You can run everything anywhere if you just emulate the expected environment a software was built for. And as GCC is open source you just need to provide the correct libraries that provide the expected API.

One can port a self-hosting compiler to a new (possibly totally different) architecture in a standard way. First, modify it such that it targets (produces machine code for) the new architecture, while still running on the old architecture. Then compile it with itself. The result is a native compiler that both runs on the new architectire and targets it. (This is not necessarily how MinGW was created, but it's a possible path).

GCC already supported the architectures used by Windows.
But the standard library had to be rewritten to support Windows.
Just like newlib is a replacement of the standard library to support embedded systems, MinGW/MinGW-w64 is in essence a replacement of the standard library using native Windows API calls.
But there is a bit more to it than that and GCC (and also other tools like binutils and gdb) also had to undergo some changes to support the Windows platform. This includes the Windows specific binary file format for executables (.exe files) and shared libraries (.dll files) which use the PE/PE+ format (based on the COFF format).
Note that MinGW-w64 isn't specifically linked to only GCC, as also LLVM can be used with MinGW-w64 (see here).

Thanks. Yes, that's along the lines of what I was thinking. So if code in GCC uses a common POSIX system call like open, then MinGW needs to substitute it with a compatible call on Windows. Perhaps this is too naive, but hypothetically MinGW can port this code by defining open as a shim that calls CreateFile as defined in Kernel32.dll on Windows. This substitution assumes that open and CreateFile are compatible, which we haven't defined, but now MSVC can compile this code natively on Windows, correct?

Something like that. Though in same cases a POSIX call may translate to a bit more Windows API code than a 1:1 mapping. And some things just won't work on Windows (like fork()).
But in the case of open() it is actually defined in the Windows API, which explains why that would just compile fine on MSVC. However it's described as deprecated in favor of _open(), see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/open
